# Story about alien SF writer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a story which appeared in an early issue of *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine* (so, a year or so either side of 1980). It takes the form of a series of story submission cover letters (sent to *IASFM* itself) and their associated rejection slips.
The in-universe author claims that the story has actually been written by an alien who is living with her; the magazine editor clearly doesn't believe this but humours her. Each time he rejects the story he gives her advice; the story is revised but to no avail.
Finally the author advises the editor that the alien has left Earth in disgust but not before making a change to the space-time continuum that will benefit everybody. The editor's response is to accept the story but express ignorance of anyone called 'Isaac Asimov'. It's signed by the editor of *Arthur C. Clarke's Science Fiction Magazine*.

Comment: Sounds like something Asimov *would* write.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is "[One Rejection Too Many](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43176)" by Patricia Nurse.  Her only published story, it apppeared in *Asimov's*, July-August 1978.

> Dear Miss Morrison,
>
> I am very confused by your letter. Who is Isaac Asimov? I have checked with several publishers and none of them has heard of Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, although the address on the envelope was correct for this magazine.
>
> However, I was very impressed with your story and will be pleased to accept it for our next issue. Seldom do we receive a story combining such virtues as a well-conceived plot, plenty of human interest, and a delightfully subtle brand of humor.
>
> Yours truly,
>
> George H. Scithers,
> Editor,
> **Arthur C. Clarke’s Science Fiction Magazine**

The story can be read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v02n04_1978-07-08/page/n155/mode/1up) (lighter weight than the PDF at Luminist).

Comment: Yes, that's the one! It was a time-traveller, not an alien, but having now reread the story (at https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/ASI/ASI_1978_07.pdf) it's definitely the one I was looking for. Thank you!